# Left Join is filtering rows out of my query in MySQL 5.7 without any left join columns in the where clause

Tags: sql, left-join, mysql-5.7, correlated-subquery, non-deterministic

I have a query that joins 4 tables. It returns 35 rows every time I run it. Here it is..

```
SELECT Lender.id       AS LenderId,
   Loans.Loan_ID      AS LoanId,
   Parcels.Parcel_ID  AS ParcelId,
   tr.Tax_ID          AS TaxRecordId,
   tr.Tax_Year        AS TaxYear
FROM parcels
     INNER JOIN Loans ON (Parcels.Loan_ID = Loans.Loan_ID AND Parcels.Escrow = 1)
     INNER JOIN Lender ON (Lender.id = Loans.Bank_ID)
     INNER JOIN Tax_Record tr ON (tr.Parcel_ID = Parcels.Parcel_ID AND tr.Tax_Year = :taxYear)
WHERE Loans.Active = 1
    AND Loans.Date_Submitted IS NOT NULL
    AND Parcels.Municipality = :municipality
    AND Parcels.County = :county
    AND Parcels.State LIKE :stateCode
```

If I left join a table (using a subquery in the on clause of the join), MySQL does some very unexpected things. Here's the modified query with the left join...

```
SELECT Lender.id       AS LenderId,
   Loans.Loan_ID      AS LoanId,
   Parcels.Parcel_ID  AS ParcelId,
   tr.Tax_ID          AS TaxRecordId,
   tr.Tax_Year        AS TaxYear
FROM parcels
     INNER JOIN Loans ON (Parcels.Loan_ID = Loans.Loan_ID AND Parcels.Escrow = 1)
     INNER JOIN Lender ON (Lender.id = Loans.Bank_ID)
     INNER JOIN Tax_Record tr ON (tr.Parcel_ID = Parcels.Parcel_ID AND tr.Tax_Year = :taxYear)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN taxrecordpayment trp ON trp.taxRecordId = tr.Tax_ID AND trp.paymentId = (
         SELECT p.id
         FROM taxrecordpayment trpi
             JOIN payments p ON p.id = trpi.paymentId
         WHERE trpi.taxRecordId = tr.Tax_ID AND p.isFullYear = 0
         ORDER BY p.dueDate, p.paymentSendTo
         LIMIT 1
     )
WHERE Loans.Active = 1
    AND Loans.Date_Submitted IS NOT NULL
    AND Parcels.Municipality = :municipality
    AND Parcels.County = :county
    AND Parcels.State LIKE :stateCode
```

I would like to note that the left join table does not appear in the where clause of the query at all, and I am not using the left join table in the select clause. In real life, I actually use the left join records in the select clause, but in my effort to get to the essential elements causing this problem, I have simplified the query and removed everything but the essential parts that cause trouble.

Here's what is happening...

Where I used to get 35 records, now I get a random number of records approaching 35.  Sometimes, I get 33. Other times, I get 27, or 29, or 31, and so on. I would never expect a left join like this to filter out any records from my result set.  A left join should only add additional columns to the result set, particularly when - as is the case here - the left join table is not part of the where clause.

I have determined that the problem really only happens if the subquery has a non-deterministic sort.  In other words, if I have two taxrecordpayment records that match the subquery and both have the same due date and the same "paymentSendTo" value, then I see the issue.  If the inner subquery has a deterministic sort, the issue goes away.

I would imagine that some people will look at my simplified example and recommend that I simply remove the subquery. If my query were this simple in real life, that would be the way to go.

In reality, the entire query is more complicated, is hitting a LOT of data, and modifying it is possible, but costly. Removing the subquery is even more costly.

Has anyone seen this sort of behavior before?  I would expect a non-deterministic subquery to simply produce inconsistent results and I would never expect a left join like this to actually filter records out when the left joined table is not used at all in the where clause.

Here is the query plan, as provided by EXPLAIN...

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | parcels | NULL | range | PRIMARY,Loan_ID,state_county,ParcelsCounty,county_state,Location,CountyLoan | county_state | 106 | NULL | 590 | 1 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | tr | NULL | eq_ref | parcel_year,ParcelsTax_Record,Year | parcel_year | 8 | infoexchange.parcels.Parcel_ID,const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | Loans | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Bank_ID,Bank,DateSub,loan_number | PRIMARY | 4 | infoexchange.parcels.Loan_ID | 1 | 21.14 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | Lender | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | infoexchange.Loans.bank_id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | trp | NULL | eq_ref | taxRecordPayment_key,IDX_trp_pymtId_trId | taxRecordPayment_key | 8 | infoexchange.tr.Tax_ID,func | 1 | 100 | Using where; Using index |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | trpi | NULL | ref | taxRecordPayment_key,IDX_trp_pymtId_trId | taxRecordPayment_key | 4 | infoexchange.tr.Tax_ID | 1 | 100 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | infoexchange.trpi.paymentId | 1 | 10 | Using where |

I have attempted to recreate this with a contrived data setup and an analogous query, but with my contrived data set, I cannot get the subquery behave non-deterministically even though it suffers from the same problem as my subquery above (there are multiple records that match the subquery and the order by is not unique for those records).

This seems to require a massive data set to start misbehaving. It happens on multiple distinct instances of MySQL 5.7, while a MySQL 5.6 instance does not demonstrate the problem at all. I am hoping someone can spot something in the above query plan to help me understand why the subquery is non-deterministic and - more importantly - why that causes records to get dropped from the result set.

I feel like this is either a data set issue (perhaps we need to do a table optimize or do some maintenance on our tables), or a bug in MySQL.

Comment: The question is clear.  I'd be interested in the data that causes this.   This must be a bug or corruption of some kind.  Even if we have `LEFT JOIN x ON 1 = 0`, this can't reduce the prior generated rows in the `FROM` clause.  The worst that would occur is nulls generated for columns of `x` in the result, regardless of the kind of table `x` is, derived table, cte term, view, etc, and regardless of any correlated behavior in a subquery in that `ON` clause. With a test case, we could check whether the bug/behavior exists in more recent versions.

Comment: Before jumping to that conclusion, however, the test case is required, just in case something else was missed in the actual SQL.

Comment: Thank you @JonArmstrong. How do I proceed with a test case?  I have tried to contrive a data set where the subquery *could* be non-deterministic, but it doesn't behave non-deterministically with my super tiny, contrived data set.  I do have this error happening on multiple MySQL 5.7 instances with very similar, large data sets, though.

Comment: If I were to guess, I wouldn't worry about the non-deterministic aspect.  That's just causing slightly different wrong results.  I would look for correlated behavior that causes improper reduction of the result.  If you can determine which results are missing / wrong, you should be able to find all the related rows (by primary key) to attempt to build a test case.  The risk is that a bug could be triggered by almost anything, even data that seems unrelated to the missing results.  Reducing the data in the test could avoid the bug.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I think the non-deterministic is a factor, though, only because the number of records dropped varies about every time I run the query.  And, a parcel that is dropped on one run is not dropped on the next.  It isn't consistent. I may have overstated the fact that we have multiple systems exhibiting this behavior. We are seeing it on multiple systems, but one is a primary and the other is the read replica for that primary. So, it is not a simple matter or underlying binary corruption, since they reside on separate hosts in separate AWS regions.

Comment: I would never do this in production, but for debugging, what happens if you put the data for the subquery in a temporary table so that you can remove the join and WHERE p.is_full_year=0 from the subquery.  Run it with the simplified subquery against the temp table and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @BrianZ.  That's a big challenge. We need the ps join in that query to do the ordering.  In the prod version of the query, there are 11 left joins and each has a subquery. We are generating a report that flattens out 11 different payment records into individual columns for each record in the report.  So, it would be a massive temp table and the only place I have this misbehaving right now is prod and the prod read replica.  I might be able to figure out how to get all of that data into a temp table without causing too much disruption. Would it tell me about corruption?

Comment: @JonArmstrong I attempted to find a pattern with the results and cannot seem to do it. Here are the parcel counts for the last 12 runs: 19, 18, 19, 26, 20, 23, 19, 22, 21, 16, 17, 21.  I compared a couple of the 19 row data sets and the records are not the same even though the count is the same.

Comment: @BrianZ I actually found another system (not production) exhibiting the problem. I will work on the temp table experiment tomorrow.

Comment: Nowhere in this question do you say or demonstrate that the left join (quoting your bug report) "does not return every record from tableA". What you do write is explainable by your "non-deterministic" subquery.

Answer (score -1):

I have submitted a bug for this behavior.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104824

You can recreate this behavior as follows...

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE tableB (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tableAId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT tableBFKtableAId FOREIGN KEY (tableAId) REFERENCES tableA (id)
);

INSERT INTO tableA (name)
VALUES ('he'),
       ('she'),
       ('it'),
       ('they');

INSERT INTO tableB (tableAId, name)
VALUES (1, 'hat'),
       (2, 'shoes'),
       (4, 'roof');
```

Run this query multiple times and the number of rows returned will vary:

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.id, -1) AS tableBId,
       a.id               AS tableAId
FROM tableA a
         LEFT JOIN tableB b ON (b.tableAId = a.id AND 0.5 > RAND());
```

Comment: x LEFT JOIN y ON c returns x INNER JOIN y ON c rows UNION ALL unmatched x rows extended by NULLs--SQL Standard 2006 SQL/Foundation 7.7 Syntax Rules 1, General Rules 1 b, 3 c & d, 5 b. Your bug report is correct that each left table row must prefix at least 1 output row of its own. The person responding doesn't seem to know how left join works. Their "ON clause can take only expressions that" is wrong & the rest of that reply is incomprehensible. Their "easily correct" suggests they think your preceding correct left join result is an incorrect one. Might help to quote my 1st sentence+reference.